# stop vue carousel image from sliding in on load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

When I load the page that shows the `v-carousel` it loads the images in by swiping them from right to left. Like the images below.

How can I get rid of this swipe? I want the image to load in place, and when I click the buttons it moves to the next image.

**On load: Initially it is white**

[image: step 1]

**Then Image loads by swiping from the right to the left.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the docs? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/carousels#example-custom-transition

Comment: Yeah but they are all about custom transitions, the transition is fine, but I just don't want it to happen when it loads.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple if you want your slides without any transition, just do:

```
<v-carousel-item
    v-for="(item,i) in items"
    :key="i"
    :src="item.src"
    reverse-transition="none"
    transition="none"
  ></v-carousel-item>
```

Comment: Yes but the problem is, that I don't want it to happen when it loads the page, but I do want it to do it when I click to go to the next image.

Comment: @Otto Did you ever get this solved? Having the same problem.

Comment: @BalázsVincze No, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the right way, but this is how I solved the problem:

```
     <template>
        <v-carousel v-if="show"
          :cycle="cycle"
        >
          <v-carousel-item
            v-for="(item,i) in items"
            :key="i"
            :src="item"
          ></v-carousel-item>
        </v-carousel>
     <template>
     <script>
        export default {
          data () {
            return {
              cycle: false
            }
          }
        }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not the default behaviour
it might happen when your carousel-item components are keyed the wrong way

for example:
wrong (will trigger re-render whenever the image id changes):

```
<v-carousel-item
   v-for="(productImage, index) in productImages"
   :key="productImage.id"
>
```

right:

```
<v-carousel-item
   v-for="(productImage, index) in productImages"
   :key="index"
>
```